# How can I add Federated Search Results into Experience Cloud portal?

Tags: experience-cloud, search, experience-builder-page, externalobjects, federated-search

I am following the article
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_experience_enable_obj.htm&type=5
and trying to setup  Federated Search Results external Object (Blog__x) into Experience Cloud portal search, however, this external object doesn't show up in the list of available objects in the list
[image]

I have setup Federated Search, created a permission set and granted access to the external object and its tab and added permission set as a member for the community site. Is anything else missing here?

Answer (score 0):

We need to select a search page from the menu and select `Search Results` component, but no the `Global Search Box` component.

[image]

and on the properties of the `Global Searh results` component we can select the External object which is created from Federated Search configuration.

[image]